# How to Retain Font Weights when Exporting Word Doc to PDF?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, latex, microsoft-word-2016

I'm trying to imitated LateX style typesetting in word by using a this [word template](https://github.com/sebnil/LaTeX-template-for-Word). The main issue is that when exporting as a PDF, some of the bolded text appears as regular (`Computer Modern Family` font is installed).

I think this might be due to predefined weight a certain font has but is there a workaround to export PDF as it is in Word. (Below are examples of what I get)

[image: Word]
[image: PDF]

Comment: How are you exporting to PDF? What settings in the export are you using?

Comment: @music2myear I just navigate to Export tab and click Export as PDF. Alternatively, I tried 'Save As' but I get the same thing.